# Align overflowing container to right of grid cell, not grid row

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a 12 column grid. Column 1 is a month number and column 2-12 are a text title.

However, the font of the number is so large that it was forcing the column width to be larger than the other columns. I'm trying to keep equal column width while also not letting the contents of the first column overlap the title text.

To do this, I was hoping I could just align the contents of the first column to the right edge of the column... alas, it's not working.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rothamsted-rothamsted/pen/jOWJpPb)

Here is the columns:
[image]

and this is the div inside column 1 that is holding the H3 number text:
[image]

How can I get the .date-container div to align it's right edge, to the right edge of it's parent column?

and of course, some code:

```
.month-title-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.date-container{
  position: absolute;
}

.date-container h1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: end;
}

.col-1
{
grid-column-end: span 1;
}


<div class="month-title-grid">
<div class="col-12"><h3 class="lightbrown">January</h3></div>
<div class="col-1"><div class="date-container"><h1 class="lightbrown">01</h1></div></div>
<div class="col-11"><h2 class="darkbrown">IT'S COMPLICATED</h2>
```

Comment: By not giving the .date-container position: absolute. Then it stays inside of its parent container.

Comment: It will definitely overflow. I want the overflow to be visible, but I want to align the .date-container to the right hand edge of the first column... so it overflows to the left, rather than overflowing to the right and overlapping the title.

Comment: Okay, check my answer that should do what you want to have then, if i understood you correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that i understood this really should fix your problem, it works in your codepen for me.

```css
.month-title-grid {
  display: grid;
  /*this will help to keep the columns even*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 12, minmax(50px, 1fr) );
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.col-1
{
/*this will force the overflow to the left*/
direction: rtl;
grid-column-end: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="month-title-grid">
<div class="col-12"><h3 class="lightbrown">January</h3></div>
<div class="col-1"><div class="date-container"><h1 class="lightbrown">01</h1></div></div>
<div class="col-11"><h2 class="darkbrown">IT'S COMPLICATED</h2>
```

Comment: the grid allows me to divide lots of other content on the page into 12 and then align them. So the text boxes on the page start at column 2 in order to line up with the title. The month number is in column one, but when it gets too big it pushes the title over, meaning the title no longer lines up with text boxes and other content on the page in other grids.

Comment: The month number is literally the only thing that will overflow, but it should overflow to the left, not the right.

The fix above does keep the columns the same width,and it does make the .date-container smaller in width than the grid-column... but the number still ends up overlapping the title.

Comment: Yes, I removed position absolute from .date-container and gave it max width of 3rem (6rem makes it to big and pushes the other columns over). All that happens is the text inside .date-container now overlaps the title, but the title is at least is the correct position and hasn't been pushed over.

Comment: No, by text, I meant the big number 1. It is overlapping the title text after making the suggested change. i.e i.e it is overflowing the grid cell and overlapping the content on the right.

Comment: The problem with the example is that column 1 never changes it's width as the screen size changes. Meaning any other grids on the page will have different widths. All columns should stay absolutely equal width and all scale together. I just want the right right hand edge of the .date-container div to be in line with the right hand edge of the column it is in. Like doing right:0px... (i tried that, but it aligns to the whole grid row, not to the column it is in)..

Comment: does it have to be 12 columns specifically?

Comment: Yes. In the documentation it seems like I should be able to apply justify-self:end to the grid item on column 1, but for some reason it's aligning the start of the item to the end of the column... rather than the ends of the item to the end of the column which is what the docs say it should do.

Comment: Added codepen link to OP. Textbox on lower left should be inline with title text. The month number is causing title text to get push over,

Comment: that helps alot, now i know what your problem is. Maybe do that directly next time, was very confusing at first

Comment: edited answer, i really hope thats it and i understood all your questions now

Comment: aaaahhhhh ltr!, genius! Thanks so much for your time and patience. :)